# Find index for column name matching regex in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I am trying to identify the index of a column name based on a matching regex condition. However `df.columns` produces an object of `Type pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`, that does not have indexes. I want the index so that i can slice the df to get rid of columns that I don't need.

Here is a worked example:

```
#create a df with column names
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Country', 2010, 2011, 2012, 'metadata1', 'metadat2'])

df.columns
> Index(['Country', 2010, 2011, 2012, 'metadata1', 'metadat2'], dtype='object')
```

I want to get rid of all the metadata columns.

On a `series` I would try something like:

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('meta')].index[0]
> ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

So I try changing with `.astype('str')`:

```
df.columns.astype('str')[df.columns.astype('str').str.contains('meta')].index[0]
> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'index'
```

So my Index has no method `.index`. So I am left to convert to a list and enumerate with `re` condition:

```
[i for i, item in enumerate(df.columns.astype('str').to_list()) if re.findall('meta', item)]
> [4, 5]
```

This works so I can do the following:

```
cutoff = [i for i, item in enumerate(df.columns.astype('str').to_list()) if re.findall('meta', item)][0]
df = df.iloc[:,:cutoff]
```

This however seems extraordinary for such a menial task. In R this would be as simple as:

```
cutoff <- min(grep('meta', colnames(df))) - 1 #-1 to address non-zero indexing
df <- df[, seq(1, cutoff)]
```

Is there no easier way to do this in pandas, other than to 1) convert to string, 2) convert to list, 3) enumerate list? Essentially I would have thought there was an equivalent of the `min(grep('meta', colnames(df))) - 1` line.

Comment: what is the expected output please? it will be easy to get to the answer if the expected output is clearly articulated

Comment: Sorry, I have the output there - as I get the answer just in a laborious manner. Ideal output is: 4 (`[4, 5][0]` or `min([4, 5])`)

Comment: For the string contains, set `na` to False; that should return the index for you: ``df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('meta', na = False)]``. To get rid of the `meta`, you can use a `~`.   `df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('meta', na = False)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that may fulfill your needs:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Country', 2010, 2011, 2012, 'metadata1', 'metadat2'])

df_ = df.columns.to_frame(index=False, name='index')
matched = df_.loc[
   df_['index'].str.contains(r'metadata\d+|metadat\d+', na=False)
].index.values

print(matched)
```

Output:

```
array([4, 5])
```

You could also use the [get_indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) method, to get the index positions:

```
df.columns.get_indexer(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('meta', na = False)])
array([4, 5])
```

If you just want to filter out the `meta` columns, you can use boolean indexing in `loc`:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('meta', na = False)]
 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Country, 2010, 2011, 2012]
Index: []
```

Comment: set `na` to False in string contains; it removes the need for the `replace` function

Comment: @sammywemmy Yes you're right. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think ultimately the user wants to filter out the meta, so maybe reconstruct your answer to fit that. Also, your code could be reworked, without converting to a frame and using loc; you can use pandas index methods : ``df.columns.get_indexer(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('meta', na = False)])``. Of course this is unnecessary, since you can just select the columns with boolean indexing: ``df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('meta', na = False)]``

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks for your comment. Your answer is more shorter than mine!. However what i understood from the OP; i think he/she is searching for column indexes at first place and i don't know what he/she will do after this.

Comment: @sammywemmy I think you should post your answer. Your 2 methods are much better than my approach.

Comment: @ChihebNexus You are correct. I want the index for the reasons laid out in my comment to Karl. Thanks for you solution, but as a one-liner this is still pretty challenging: `df.columns.to_frame(index = False, name = 'index')['index'][df.columns.to_frame(index = False, name = 'index')['index'].str.contains('meta').fillna(False)].index[0]`. Unreadable compared to `min(grep('meta', colnames(df)))`. I appreciate R and Python are different languages, but this seemed like it would be common enough to have a neat solution. No problem if not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MorrisseyJ Thanks for your comment. But if you want a more flexible and greater answer i recommend you trying @sammywemmy comment: `df.columns.get_indexer(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('meta', na = False)])` it's more readable and well found.

Comment: @ChihebNexus Ah yes: that is neater. I hadn't seen the `get_indexer` method. @sammywemmy Thanks for that. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @ChihebNexus, I chose instead to add it to your answer; hope that is ok with you

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `.drop()` and [.filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
>>> df.filter(like='meta')
  metadata1 metadat2
0         e        f
1         k        l
>>> df.drop(columns=df.filter(like='meta'))
  Country 2010 2011 2012
0       a    b    c    d
1       g    h    i    j
```

You can also use `regex=` to find all columns without `meta`

```
>>> df.filter(regex='^(?:(?!meta).)+$')
  Country 2010 2011 2012
0       a    b    c    d
1       g    h    i    j
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works on the example i provided, but imagine that I am importing a variety of datasets and cleaning them and that there are all sorts of columns after the first one containing 'meta'. Imagine its so bad that this makes using `regex` or `like` in such a way that doesn't exclude 'Country' extremely challenging. For this reason, I just want to find the first index matching 'meta' (which is always the first thing I want to get rid of) and slice so as to get rid of everything after that. Nonetheless I can use the approach you use here in other cases.